# How to trace sources of state changes?

Tags: reactjs

I have following hook in my react app:

```
const MyPage = React.FC = () => {
    const myContext = useContext(MyContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(myContext);
    }, [myContext]);
}
```

Effect hook though fires 3 times and that's expected and works as designed. But is there way to trace source of context changes so I could remove unnecessary changes?

Comment: Just give a try with Redux Devtools extension, hope it might work.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1st approach: Don't use an effect hook, log where you are everytime a component updates the value provided by the context

```
// SomeComponents.js
export default () => {
  const myContext = useContext(MyContext)
  <button onClick={() => {window.console.log('In SomeComponents.js, onClick handler'); myContext.incrementCount()}>
    ${myContext.count}
  </button>
}
```

#### 2nd approach

More generally, there is a tool to find how to optimize the performance of your React app. It's called the [React Profiler](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/09/10/introducing-the-react-profiler.html), available since React 16.5.

#### Failed approach: Throw and catch an error to get the stack

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      throw new Error('I should be caught')
    } catch (e) {
      window.console.log(e)
    }
  }, [state])
```

However the state was updated, the error has the same stack, so this gives us no clue.

Comment: Well 1st approach is kind of what I'm aiming for. To get rid of unnecessary hooks but I just wished there would be some magical tool that would tell where my context was updated...